# How to upload application/javascript file in static resource

Tags: javascript, static-resources, upload

I created a JS file and uploaded to static resources in Salesforce. It identifies the mime type as application/x-javascript. So unable to open the file in Dev console, because it support application/javascript.

How to create and upload application/javascript file ?

Comment: I think you have to know the differences of application/x-javascript and application/javascript....See these links for clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_mobile_javascript_library.htm
It might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I experienced in past that mime type (for static resources) depends on the browser used to upload the file. I got the below mime types for same javascript file from different browser.

Chrome - application/javascript

Firefox -application/x-javascript

IE 11- application/octet-stream

So you can try to upload the file from chrome and see if you get application/javascript as mime type.

Or else you can use **Eclipse IDE** to change the mime type. Change the MIME type in the static resource's meta XML file from application/x-javascript to application/javascript.

Comment: Yes I changed the mime type using the Eclipse.